# A question on finite-order operators

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, operator-theory

I have a question: is it true that if $R\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is s.t. $R^k=1$ for some $k>1$ (that must be the smaller one for which this happens), then there exists $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ s.t. $R^jx\neq R^lx$ for all $j,l=0,\ldots,k-1$, $j\neq l$? I think the answer is affirmative and I guess this derives from the injectivity of $R$, which follows by its invertibility. However, I cannot write it down appropriately. I guess that if $\forall x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ there exist $j\neq l\in\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$ s.t. $R^j x=R^lx$, then setting $N=l.c.m.\{j\in\{1,\ldots,k\} : \exists y\in\mathbb{C}^n \ s.t. \ R^jy=y\}$, it should be $N=k$, otherwise $R$ would not have order $k$. By assumption the assumption, $\forall x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ there exists $j\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $R^jx=x$ (we use the invertibility of $R$ here). Then, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Since $R$ is invertible the claim is equivalent to saying that there exists some $x\in\Bbb C^n$ such that $R^jx\ne x$ for all $1\leq j\leq k-1$. Since $R^j$ is not the identity matrix for $j=1,\dots, k-1$ the set of $x\in\Bbb C^n$ with $R^jx=x$ is a proper subspace (i.e. $\ker (R^j-I)$) of $\Bbb C^n$. If for all $x\in \Bbb C^n$ there was some $j=1,\dots,k-1$ with $R^jx=x$ then $\Bbb C^n$ would be the finite union of proper subspaces which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Since $R$ is invertible (having $R^{-1}=R^{k-1}$), if for all $x$ we had $R^j(x)=R^l(x)$, it would mean $R^j=R^l$, implying $1=R^{l-j}$ which would contradict to the minimality of $k$.

Comment: But OP is asking for more. The question is whether the same $x$ fails at all levels.